CNS Neuron Regeneration
Do neurons in the CNS have the ability to regenerate from typical cell damage? I know that if an axon is completely severed, or the neuron dies, that it cannot regenerate, or replicate.
The types of cellular damage I am refering to are indicated here:
https://sciencevivid.com/cell-injury-introduction-causes-types-mechanism-morphology/#Biochemical_mechanism
But most articles I find do not specify if "neuron regeneration" is referring to a neurons ability to regenerate from typical cell damage (such as mechanical or oxidative stress, membrane damage, etc) or complete axonal transection, or complete cell death.
I however did find an article that states
"Here, regeneration is defined as the regrowth of a severed axon, either from the severed end itself or from a new branch of the same axon generated proximal to the injured end that extends past the site of injury (Figure 1; Tuszynski and Steward, 2012)."
https://pmc.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/articles/PMC9074815/
which seems to indicate that regeneration in this regard only refers to a severed axon, and not typical regenerative capabilities of the neuron as a whole that is seen in basically every other cell of the body.
So which is it? Do neurons have the ability to regenerate from typical cellular damage from normal "wear and tear"? Surely they must have this ability since neurons do not replicate and must maintain their health throughout the entire lifespan.
And why do scientific articles have to be so vague when defining what "neuron regeneration" means?

"why do scientific articles have to be so vague when defining what "neuron regeneration" means?" - what is so vague about ""Here, regeneration is defined as the regrowth of a severed axon, either from the severed end itself or from a new branch of the same axon generated proximal to the injured end that extends past the site of injury (Figure 1; Tuszynski and Steward, 2012).""?

Every paper needs to operationally define concepts for that particular paper.

Yes I agree, however this is the only paper I found that defines it. Every other paper Ive read about it does not.

I can't really comment on other papers without examples. Some may just be lousy papers, there are a lot of those around.
